# Fetch API - What's the use of redirect: manual

Tags: javascript, specifications, fetch-api

I've recently been playing with the Javascript Fetch API. As far as I understand, by default all redirects are handled transparently and in the end I get a response from the last call in the redirect chain.

However, I could invoke fetch with {redirect: 'manual'}, in which case it would return an opaqueredirect response with no usable information. From https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-filtered-response-opaque-redirect

> An opaque-redirect filtered response
>   is a filtered response whose type is "opaqueredirect", status is 0, status message is the empty byte sequence, header list is empty, body is null, and trailer is empty.

https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-fetch says that a response gets to be opaqueredirect if redirect is set to 'manual':

> Switch on request’s redirect mode:
>   ...
>   - manual
>       Set response to an opaque-redirect filtered response whose internal response is actualResponse.

The specification also says:

> In other words, an opaque filtered response and an opaque-redirect filtered response are nearly indistinguishable from a network error.

Given all this, why would one set redirect to manual when using the Fetch API? To me it seems pretty useless. Are there use cases where this would be useful?

Comment: Just had to use it myself. I was requesting a server that had 3 redirects, just to define some cookies. `fetch` was not passing those cookies, so I passed them manually.

Comment: I am using redirect: manual, to unshorten the URL

Comment: I came across the `redirect` property while trying to implement a log-in form using React Router. After a successful login, I want the server to return 302, but I want to handle it using client-side routing instead of issuing another request to the server. I thought the `manual` value is what I need, but since the `opaqueredirect` response doesn't contain the `Location` header (or any other headers, for that matter), I guess I'll have to do it some other way. I don't understand why it's implemented this way.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The short answer is: unless you’re doing something with service-worker code like what https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/66 covers, you don’t ever want `redirect: 'manual'`.

**Longer answer:**

The [HTML spec requires](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsing-the-web.html#process-a-navigate-fetch) browsers to first set the redirect mode to `manual` when the browser starts navigating to a resource. That’s the only use in any spec for the `manual` redirect mode.

But because the Fetch API essentially exposes the same primitives that browsers use internally for fetches, it exposes a `manual` redirect mode. However, just because the API exposes a particular primitive doesn’t mean there’s a good use for that primitive in frontend code.

The spec used to require that even though you *could* call the API with `redirect: 'manual'`, browsers would throw if you did — because back then nobody had yet offered any valid reason for setting it for any case other than browsers doing navigations.

But that behavior got changed due to https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/66, which gives a (corner) case where `redirect: 'manual'` is needed in service-worker code.

A similar case of something you can set in the Fetch API but with very little utility in web-app code is `mode: 'no-cors'`. That was initially added just because browsers use it for certain requests, so the Fetch API exposes it. But that’s another case that has limited utility just for  service workers—for caching responses to serve back as-is later without any need to examine the responses (which `mode: 'no-cors'` prevents web-app code from doing).

Comment: The first paragraph is wrong. You'd need `redirect: 'manual'` outside of service workers too. Imagine you just want to prevent the destination endpoint to be fetched for any reason.

Comment: Yea, it's not really an answer. I have now a case where you MUST intercept redirects, because in a Digest Authentication you need to increment the nc and cnonce to follow the redirect properly.