# Does Axios have the ability to detect redirects?

Tags: javascript, axios, response.redirect

The [Response interface of the Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) has a [read-only flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/redirected), `redirected`, which indicates whether or not the response was the result of a request that was redirected.

Does the [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) library have a similar capability?  The best I could find is `maxRedirects` which sets the maximum number of redirects to follow.  However, I am simply looking to determine if it happened or not (so I can handle redirects specially), not prevent it from happening.

Comment: Is it not sufficient to validate the response status reflects a redirection?

Comment: So the redirected response status is 200, but it is bogus.  I need to determine if it is a legitimate 200 or not.  The Network tab shoes both the 302 and 200 requests but the fetch/axios call only shows 200 when handling the response

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Compare the request URL from your code with the URL given by ***response.request*.`responseURL`**; if those aren’t equal, you know the request was redirected.

As far as the status code being 200, that’s what’s required by the spec; no intermediate status codes are exposed to frontend JavaScript running in a browser — regardless of which API you use. See also the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/46031800/441757

Comment: -1 : As far as I can tell, the `response` exposed by axios does not have a `url` member which makes this a total non-answer to the question. https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema

Comment: I believe the value you want will be exposed at `response.request.responseURL`

Comment: Just keep in mind `response.request.responseURL` is not available when using Internet Explorer 11, at least with axios v.0.20.0.

Comment: in my case 'response.request.res.responseUrl' worked

Comment: According to docs: "`request` is the request that generated this response. It is the last ClientRequest instance in node.js (in redirects) and an XMLHttpRequest instance in the browser". So there may be differences if you are checking the request in a browser or node, and there may also by differences between nodejs versions. Check documentation for you environment/version.

Answer (score 25):

You can get the redirect count:

```
const response = await axios.get('http://someurlthatredirects.com');
console.log(response.request._redirectable._redirectCount);
```

Answer (score 3):

Given answer didn't resolve my issue so adding my bit.
To stop Axios from redirecting, set `maxRedirects` property to `0`:

```js
    axios({
          url: 'someurl.com',
          method: 'get',
          timeout: 20000,
          maxRedirects: 0,
          validateStatus: (status: number) =>
            status >= 200 && status < 400,
        })
```

`validateStatus` is used to accept the `3XX` status codes as correct responses.

Comment: The maxRedirects option only works in Node.js, https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/674#issuecomment-279225530

Answer (score 2):

I tried to access response sub-object in request object in **Axios** that was described in docs as

> `` // `request` is the request that generated this response // It is the last ClientRequest instance in node.js (in redirects) // and an XMLHttpRequest instance in the browser request: {} ``

I didn't really understand what it means, so @ori888's comment worked with `response.request.res.responseUrl`, now I can redirect a client to that address, and it worked
thank you ori888

Answer (score 1):

I found that `maxRedirects`-option only works in Node.js, as stated in this GitHub-issue [here](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/674#issuecomment-279225530).

I then tried the `beforeRedirect`-option, which I found on the `AxiosRequestConfig`-type definitions. It didn't work either, probably due to the same reasons as `maxRedirects` didn't.

What I ended up doing is using `interceptors` like this:

```
import axios, { isAxiosError } from "axios";
import { hasOwnProperties, hasOwnProperty } from "utils";

//...

const axiosInstance = axios.create();
axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
  // Any status codes that lie within the range of 2xx (default), or do pass custom `validateStatus()` cause this function to trigger
  function (response) {
    if (
      hasOwnProperty(response, "request") &&
      hasOwnProperties(response.request, ["requestURL", "responseURL"]) &&
      response.request.requestURL !== response.request.responseURL
    ) {
      // do your stuff
    }
    return response;
  },
  // Any status codes that falls outside the range of 2xx cause (default), or do not pass custom `validateStatus()` this function to trigger
  function (error) {
    if (
      isAxiosError(error) &&
      error.response &&
      hasOwnProperties(error.response.request, ["requestURL", "responseURL"]) &&
      error.response.request.requestURL !== error.response.request.responseURL
    ) {
      // do your stuff
    }
  }
);
```