# axios is not redirected and receiving cookies from redirected url

Tags: javascript, python, python-requests, axios

I am trying to send a request and get the cookies from a redirected url. When I am using axios for that I am getting 200 status and the data that is returned is the html page. However I tried to perform exactly the same GET with python requests module that creates `requests.session()`, the logic of getting the cookies from the response is implemented there, and that of course works- I am able to see new location in the response headers. When I debugged the code I also saw serval response objects, with different headers and the final one had the Set-Cookie field with the right cookie from the last location. However in axios I saw only one response - that was the first response that was received in python.I inferred that the axios neither actually performed the location redirection, nor stored any cookies. I am wondering how to make axios redirect and follow the redirects like in python requests module.
I tried to use `withCredential: true` but it didn't help.

My request is as following:
I heared that in order to use cookies via request I need cookies Jar, however I haven't manged to understand how.
This is what I tried so far:

```
axiosCookieJarSupport(axios);
const cookieJar = new tough.CookieJar();
axios.get(url, {
            headers: {
                'Referer': 'some url'
            },
            params: {
                my params
            },
            jar: cookieJar,
            withCredentials: true,
        }).then(res => {
            console.log('res=', res);
            console.log('after request ====> ', cookieJar);
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
```

In python the requests module does the job and get the desired cookies, and fill the request object with the cookies.How can I achieve this using axios, and why in axios i'm not redirected and receive only one response, and in python requests I get several responses and the final one the the relevant with the cookies in it. Would be glad to know about this issue more as I am stuck.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55926127/does-axios-have-the-ability-to-detect-redirects

Comment: thanks for your response, but not what I am looking for. I don't need to see if it was redirected or not. My purpose is to take the cookies from the redirected url. I am not able to see the Set-Cookie header in the response like in the python requests module

Comment: You suggested that Axios didn't handle the redirect. I'm providing you evidence that it does, by default.

Comment: ok so why I am not getting the cookies and the location header in the final response ? In python I do get