# Response headers not available for fetch request with 'redirect: manual'

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am doing

```
        console.log("navigating");
        var rsp = await fetch(params.url, {
            credentials: "include", redirect: "manual", mode: "cors"
        });
        console.log(rsp);
        rsp.headers.forEach(console.log);

        console.log(rsp.headers.get('Location'));
        console.log(rsp.headers.get('location'));
```

and the reponse headers from chrome dev tools:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4400
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Location
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Date: Fri, 05 Oct 2018 12:48:21 GMT
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Location: http://localhost/test
```

gives

```
Response 
body: (...)
bodyUsed: falseheaders: 
Headers {}
ok: false
redirected: false
status: 0
statusText: ""
type: "opaqueredirect"
url: "..."

index.ts:161 null
index.ts:162 null
```

Is it not possible to get response headers out on redirect response?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Is it not possible to get response headers out on redirect response?

No, it’s not possible. The requirements in the Fetch spec prevent it.

What the question shows is expected for `manual` redirect mode: The headers object exposed to frontend JS is expected to be empty in responses to `redirect: "manual"` requests.

When a request sets `manual` redirect mode, the response type is `opaqueredirect`. Info on the effects of that is at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/type:

> `opaqueredirect`: The fetch request was made with `redirect: "manual"`. The Response's status is 0, **headers are empty**, body is null and trailer is empty.

---

Those details in that MDN article are based directly on the following parts of the Fetch spec:

https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-request-redirect-mode

> A request has an associated redirect mode, which is `"follow"`, `"error"`, or `"manual"`.
> …
> **"manual"**: Retrieves an **opaque-redirect filtered response** when a request is met with a redirect so that the redirect can be followed manually.

https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-filtered-response-opaque-redirect

> **opaque-redirect filtered response** is a filtered response whose type is `"opaqueredirect"`, status is `0`, status message is the empty byte sequence, **header list is empty**, body is null
> …
> an opaque filtered response and an opaque-redirect filtered response are nearly indistinguishable from a network error

Comment: _"manual:  Retrieves an opaque-redirect filtered response when a request is met with a redirect so that the redirect can be followed manually"_ but `response.url` isn't the redirect URL, its' the original URL. How can I handle a redirect manually if I have no visibility into what the redirect URL is?

Comment: @Madbreaks Yeah you don’t actually want to be using "manual"; see the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/42717388/441757.

Comment: Perhaps https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers might help, though.

Comment: why is it blocked though ?