# Get redirect url without follow

Tags: javascript, ajax, redirect, request, fetch

Is there a way to get final redirect url without following it with `Fetch API` ?
Example: 
http://some.link/1 redirects to http://some.link/2

`fetch('http://some.link/1', someParams)` => get 'http://some.link/2' url
without request to it.

Comment: See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52666207/response-headers-not-available-for-fetch-request-with-redirect-manual