# How to get redirect url without following it using native fetch in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, fetch

I'm trying to get redirect url using fetch without following it but i don't figure out how to do it.

I created a simple http server using `express` to illustrate what i have done :

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app
  .get("/", (_, res) => res.redirect("/redirect"))
  .get("/redirect", (_, res) => res.send("Redirect page"));

const port = 5000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server runs on http://localhost:${port}`));
```

In the browser, if i use the following code, i can get the redirect url :

```
fetch("http://localhost:5000").then((res) =>
  console.log(`Redirect url : ${res.url}`)
);
```

However, this code **follows** the redirect url and connects on it that i want to avoid. So i try this another code :

```
fetch("http://localhost:5000", {redirect: "manual"}).then((res) =>
  console.log(`Original url : ${res.url}`)
);
```

The redirect url is not followed as expected, however the `res.url` is not the redirect url. I think it is logic, so i was thinking my redirect url is in the header `location` but no. The following code outputs `null` as value of `location`:

```
fetch("http://localhost:5000", { redirect: "manual" }).then((res) => {
    console.log(res.headers.get("location"));
    console.log(res.headers.get("Location"));
});
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Response headers not available for fetch request with 'redirect: manual'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52666207/response-headers-not-available-for-fetch-request-with-redirect-manual)

Comment: @AngYC I've read the post you provide. But, there is something that i don't understand. So what is the goal of redirect manual if i can't even get the redirection url. How i can do it manually?

Comment: Hi, there's a second link in the comment section which tells you the use of it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42717388/88888888

Comment: @AngYC So no solution then. Thank you anyway.